# Class selector does not work after append (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    $(".quantidade").on("change blur", function() {
        if ($(this).val().length) {
            validateField("quantidade");
        } else {
            invalidateField("quantidade");
            showGeneralMessage("É necessário preencher a quantidade!", "danger");
        }
    });
```

It works just fine, until a new item is added with append:

```
$(".btn-add-produto").click(function() {
    ...
    $("#listaProdutosPedido").append(content);
    ...
});
```

This "content" includes input with the same class. After this html piece is added, the class selector does not apply to it. I guess it happens because when the document is ready, that piece of HTML does not exist. How do I "reload" the javascript / document so that the selector works even with future references? I've tried to check with setInterval(), but it does not work as well...

Comment: Use event delegation `$("#listaProdutosPedido").on("change blur", ".quantidade", null, function() {...` .

Comment: @DavidDomain The `null` property can be omitted. jQuery handles type checking internally and can distinguish between when the third argument is a `data` argument or a `handler` function. It works either way though and will solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated event syntax. In event delegation, you attach the event to a parent element. Internally, jQuery relies on the events ability to bubble up the DOM tree. When an event of the specified type with the `e.target` property matching your delegated selector is found, your event is fired.

To accomodate this change, modify your code like so:

```
$(document).on("change blur", ".quantidade", function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
        validateField("quantidade");
    } else {
        invalidateField("quantidade");
        showGeneralMessage("É necessário preencher a quantidade!", "danger");
    }
});
```

**Please note**, delegating at this high of a level is extremely inefficient. `document` should be changed out for the closest parent element that contains the newly appended content. In this case, I used it to demonstrate how the process occurs because there was not HTML DOM tree output specified in your question. When implementing this into your system, I encourage you to update the `document` selector accordingly.